# Scientific Notation and conversions from DB output into JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, scientific-notation

I'm writing python code that tests a REST Endpoint to get Scientific numbers from a DB and validate that the scientific format is returned from the database in correct JSON scientific number format.

The issue that I'm having is that some scientific numbers are converted.  For instance the JSON loader will convert the e to upper case and some values are converted into integers.  Here is some example code.  The code isn't doing exactly what I'm doing since you won't have the DB back end.

```
import json
import decimal

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
    if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
        print 'In here: ' + str( o )
        return str(o)
    return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

class JSONUtils:
    def __init__( self, response ):
        self.response = response
        self.jsonData = None
        self.LoadData( )

    # print 'jsonData: ' + json.dumps( self.jsonData, cls=DecimalEncoder, indent=2 )

    def GetData( self ):
        return self.jsonData        

    def GetAsStr( self ):
        return json.dumps(self.GetData(), cls=DecimalEncoder )

    def LoadData ( self ):
        if ( self.jsonData == None ):
            if ( type( self.response ) == str or type( self.response ) == unicode ):
                print '****type1'
                self.jsonData = json.loads(self.response, parse_float=decimal.Decimal )
            elif ( type( self.response ) == dict ):
                print '****type2'
                dump = json.dumps( self.response, cls=DecimalEncoder )
                self.jsonData = json.loads(dump, parse_float=decimal.Decimal)

    def GetJSONChunk( self, path ):
        returnValue = ''
        curPath     = ''
        try:
            if ( type( path ) == str ):
                returnValue = self.jsonData[path]
            elif (type( path ) == list):
                temp = ''
                firstTime = True
                for curPath in path:
                    if firstTime == True:
                        temp = self.jsonData[curPath]
                        firstTime = False
                    else:
                        temp = temp[curPath]
                returnValue = temp
            else:
                print 'Unknown type in GetJSONChunk: ' + unicode( type( path ))
        except KeyError as err:
            ti.DBG_OUT( 'JSON chunk doesn\'t have value: ' + unicode( path ))
            returnValue = self.kNoNode
        except IndexError as err:
            ti.DBG_OUT( 'Index does not exist: ' + unicode( curPath ))
            returnValue = self.kInvalidIndex

        return returnValue

info = { "fldName":1.47e-10 }   # converts to 1.47e-10 (e to E)
# info = { "fldName":1.47e10 }  # convers to 14700000000.0
# info = { "fldName":1.47e+10 } # convers to 14700000000.0
# info = { "fldName":1.47E+10 } # convers to 14700000000.0
# info = { "fldName":12345678901234567890123 } # example shows larger # support
print 'info: ' + str ( info )
myJSON = JSONUtils( info )
print 'type: ' + str( myJSON.jsonData )
print 'myJSON: ' + myJSON.GetAsStr( )
value =  myJSON.GetJSONChunk ( 'fldName' )
print 'Type: ' + str( type( value ))
print value
```

What I need to do is compare the DB result to an expected value.  Is there a way to identify ONLY scientific numbers?  NOT doubles / decimal values and return those as strings.  As you can see I'm already trying to protect Doubles that are being returned to be sure that meet the criteria / capabilities of the back end database.  Which can be 20+ digits to the left or right of the decimal place.

The actual results are documented by each of the lines of code that start with # info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on your question, so if this is way off base let me know.

I think there may be some confusion between how Python *displays* a number vs. the actual value of the number.

For example, I can write the number 1000 as:

```
>>> 1000
1000.0
>>> 1E3
1000.0
>>> 10E2
1000.0
>>> 1e3
1000.0
>>> 1e+3
1000.0
```

Those are all different *representations* of the number, but they are all numerically equivalent. JSON is similarly flexible; all of the above representations are also valid in JSON.

Similarly, I can write:

```
10000000000000000000000000000.0
```

But the `print` statement will display it as:

```
1e+28
```

But it's still the same number.  It hasn't been "converted" in any way.  Python will use  E notation once your number is `>= 1E16`.

So if I receive JSON that looks like this:

```
{
  "val1": 1e+3,
  "val2": 1e+20
}
```

The output of the following:

```
values = json.loads('{"val1": 1e+3, "val2": 1e+20}')
for k, v in values.items():
    print(k, '=', v)
```

Would be:

```
val1 = 1000.0
val2 = 1e+20
```

Comment: I know you can represent numbers as integers or the same number in scientific notation.  I'm testing the scientific values being returned from the database and checking them for accuracy.  IOW: Does the database represent the number / scientific number correctly.  I don't want the values munged in anyway.  What is happening is the database will return a valid scientific value and performing the JSON load will cause the value to be be translated.  Yes... to a valid scientific representation but I need the original value not the munged value.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.